# How to parse the following XML in WP7 C# to put in custom Observable?

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7

I'm creating a WP7.1 app that will receive data from a web API and turn it into usable stuffs.

I want to parse the following XML so that I can put it in the following list.

List:

```
public class Image
{
    public string Name;
    public string Location;
    public string minDisk;
    public string minRam;
    public string OS_Distro;
    public string OS_Version;
    public string ID;
}

List<Image> _Images = new List<Image>();
```

The App gets the data through a WebClient call which returns plain old XML as follows:

XML File: http://www.sendspace.com/file/uiy557

I want to cycle through each image and do the following:

```
_Images.Add(new Image() { Name = tName, Location = "ORD", minDisk = tminDisk, minRam = tminRam, OS_Distro = tOS_Distro, OS_Version = tOS_Version, ID = tID });
```

Where tVARIABLE is the value returned from the XML.

I've searched high and low for this but it just seems to go wrong every time.

I've tried the following:

```
            StringReader stream = new StringReader(e.Result);
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream);


            while (reader.Read())
....
```

Comment: Ignore any funny rubbish in the XML. It might be from pasting in to the browser!

Comment: Please fix up your post so it *actually* reflects the XML you've got, and then tell us about what you've tried.

Comment: XML Link updated and I've tried:

while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    if (reader.Name == "image")

but that doesn't help